# React App not showing changes entered in code

Tags: reactjs

I am a begginer in React

In my Users.js file, I wrote below code,
'''

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
export default class User extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Users Component</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

'''

In my App.js file I have the below code,
'''

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Users from './Users';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      HELLO WORLD!!!
      <Users />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

'''
while running the file from the terminal the app page shows this
[image]

which was the changes made previously in the app and not the current one, like it doesn't show Hello.
Please can someone tell me the issue?

Edit: Also wanted to add that I am running the code using npm start in VSC terminal.

Comment: Not a valid doubt, but still I'm asking: Did you save the file?

Comment: Did you use hmr?

Comment: @ShriHariL yes I did

Comment: @kennarddh No, I didn't know about it until now, thanks I will use that as well but I still wanted to know the issue with the above code

Comment: Inspect and verify whether the content in DOM. Include your CSS App.css too

Comment: I don't really understand your question. So you have run it then change the file save refresh the page and the page didn't change. Am I right?

Comment: @kennarddhyess exactly

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead
Here you need to add Hello world as title:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Users from './Users';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <title>HELLO WORLD!!!<title>
      <Users />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

else use

to display

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Users from './Users';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>HELLO WORLD!!!</p>
      <Users />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Title here won’t work